# Django update "extended user profile" model field from webhook paramater

Tags: python, django

I am getting a webhook from our billing processor after a user makes a payment. So far I have successfully saved the webhook in models for record keeping. However, now I need to update the User account_paid field to the appropriate status.

I believe I've outlined the steps properly but I am stuck on implementing the code. How do I update account_paid and make sure it's the right user ID?

views.py

```
#@require_POST
def webhook(request):
    template_name = 'payment/index.html'

    hook = Webhook()
    hook.user = request.GET.get('clientAccnum')
    hook.clientSubacc = request.GET.get('clientSubacc')
    hook.eventType = request.GET.get('eventType')
    hook.eventGroupType = request.GET.get('eventGroupType')
    hook.subscriptionId = request.GET.get('subscriptionId')

    hook.timestamp = request.GET.get('timestamp')
    hook.timestamplocal = timezone.now()

    hook.save()

    print (hook.user, hook.clientSubacc, hook.timestamplocal)

    if hook.eventType == 'RenewalSuccess':
        #Update user account_level to Paid Account
        Profile.account_paid.update(True)

    else:
        #Update user account_level to Free
        Profile.account_paid.update(False)
```

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    account_level = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

There are no error messages yet because I'm trying to figure out the structure right now. The goal is to finish this question with a working solution.

*Side note:
I know webhooks are delivered to URL as POST but for now I am using get purely for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Profile model has a OneToOne relationship with User, so you can simply say:

```
hook.save()
hook.user.profile.account_paid = hook.eventType == 'RenewalSuccess'
hook.user.profile.save()
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. How will this updated field to true though?

Comment: account_paid is equal to what "hook.eventType == 'RenewalSuccess'" resolves.

Comment: Ah okay I see and if it's not it will update account_paid to false?

Comment: Exactly, its basically a shorter way to accomplish the same.  If it's confusing you can simply continue using your IF-ELSE block and it'll work just fine.

Comment: Should be fine. Always nice to keep it short. I've been trying to see the results but been stuck at an error message: 'Cannot assign "'2'": "Webhook.user" must be a "User" instance.' I'm using "/?clientAccnum=2" in my URL

Comment: @AlexWinkler That's because you need to get the User from that ID.  user = User.objects.get(id=request.GET.get('clientAccnum')), then hook.user = user

Comment: Super awesome man. That did the trick. For some reason, my eventType parameter is not saving in the Webhook model but the other ones are.. That's a different issue though. Thanks for the help on this part!